# Filling Null Values of a Pandas Column with a List

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have data frame `df` that can be re-created with the code below:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['jim', 'john', 'joe', 'jack', 'jake']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['jim', 'john', 'jack'],
                    'listings': [['orlando', 'los angeles', 'houston'],
                                 ['buffalo', 'boston', 'dallas', 'none'],
                                 ['phoenix', 'montreal', 'seattle', 'none']]})

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'name', how = 'left')

print(df)
   name                                  listings
0   jim  [orlando, los angeles, houston, detroit]
1  john           [buffalo, boston, dallas, none]
2   joe                                       NaN
3  jack        [phoenix, montreal, seattle, none]
4  jake                                       NaN
```

I want to fill the `NaN` values in the `listings` column with a list of `none` repeated the length of the the lists in the `listings` column, `['none']*4`, so that the resulting dataframe looks like below:

```
print(df)
   name                                  listings
0   jim  [orlando, los angeles, houston, detroit]
1  john           [buffalo, boston, dallas, none]
2   joe                  [none, none, none, none]
3  jack        [phoenix, montreal, seattle, none]
4  jake                  [none, none, none, none]
```

I've tried both approaches below, and neither are working:

```
# Failed Approach 1
df['listings'] = np.where(df['listings'].isnull(), ['none']*4, df['listings'])

# Failed Approach 2
df['listings'].fillna(['none']*4)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do:

```
df.loc[df['listings'].isna(),'listings'] = [['none']*4]
```

---

```
   name                            listings
0   jim     [orlando, los angeles, houston]
1  john     [buffalo, boston, dallas, none]
2   joe            [none, none, none, none]
3  jack  [phoenix, montreal, seattle, none]
4  jake            [none, none, none, none]
```

Comment: This  falls into the reference trap. Try `df.loc[2, 'listings'].append(2)`, not sure if it's intended by OP.

Comment: @QuangHoang help me understand (*apologies*) why would you need that?

Comment: @anky which version of pandas are you using? I was under the impression that you can not assign list to an index that easily!

Comment: @SayandipDutta `'0.25.1'` does it not work for higher versions?

Comment: I am at 1.2.0, `ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray`

Comment: @anky my point is that the code assigns **the same object** to different cells. Now, if we modify an object at one cell, all other objects are modified as well. That's why I said I don't know if OP intents to modify `df` or not, and that this behavior is expected or not. Just stating the fact.

Comment: @SayandipDutta would this work `df.loc[...] = [['none']*4 for _ in range(df.listings.isna().sum)]`? This also eliminate the reference trap I mentioned in other comments.

Comment: @QuangHoang no, it does not. Rather it seems to be: `df.loc[df['listings'].isna(),'listings'] = pd.Series([['none']*4]*5)` or `df.loc[df['listings'].isna(),'listings'] = pd.Series([['none']*4 for _ in range(df.shape[0])])` in your way.

Comment: `pd.Series` call seems to be necessary and number of items must be equal to `df.shape[0]`

Comment: @SayandipDutta - I'm using pandas `1.1.5`, and the answer from @anky as well as both of your approaches in the comment above are working.

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks for the call-out above about potential down-stream modification issues. Every transformation downstream from this one is expected to be applied consistently for the cells that were originally `NaN`, so I think we're good. But good to know.

Comment: @QuangHoang I fail at finding any vectorized solution without referencing. Maybe we have to create individual copies to avoid that. Same as yours `df.loc[df['listings'].isna(),'listings'] = [['none']*4 for _ in range(df['listings'].isna().sum())]` is the way to go i think. Let me know if you come up with something else :) Thanks.

Comment: @anky I doubt you would get much vectorization with Series of lists (of strings) anyway.